# Jquery return original event on video

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I have multiple video plays on a single page which I need to listen for onplay and onpause triggers, and execute custom functions which take the IDs from each of the videos tags. I need to be able to get the video id that was activated. Ive tried a few different ways, with the simple vid.onplay event works well when I know what ID is being called into. I've tried the $("video").onplay but doesn't seem to be working.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {  


$("video").onplay  = function() {
    alert("The video has been paused");
};  

var vid = document.getElementbyid("myVideo");   
vid.onplay = function() {
    alert("The video has been played");
};      
});
```

````
<video class="mdia_video_player" id=myVideo  poster="https://tcokchallenge.com/launch2/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Carter.jpg?336660464" id="v0" onclick="doplayvideo(" 0")"="" controls="">
<source src="https://tcokchallenge.com/launch2/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Carter.mp4?1222152426" type="video/mp4">  
</video>```
````

Comment: `$("video").onplay = function() {` is not valid jQuery and `var vid = document.getElementbyid("myVideo");` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

In your first demo, it should be `$("#video")` to call by ID. It also says `.onplay` and then says that is was paused so you might want to fix that.

Comment: The video id is going to be different for every video element, so I cannot call by id since I do not know what it is,

Comment: Could you do `$(\`#${id}\`)` and then put it in a loop over each video?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing a much simpler answer, videos are within a php loop. So, I placed this within the tag

```
onpause="dopausevideo(<?=$vid ?>)"
onplay="doplayvideo(<?=$vid ?>)"
```